# Why hide HTML elements?

Tags: html, css

Seems like google search, twitter, and some websites hide some of their heading tags (h1, h2, h3...) which can only be seen by deactivating the CSS.

So the question is, why would they do that? Since they could just not add it there at all!

These are normal tags, which has the title/heading only, there's nothing special about them!

Comment: probably would help if you included what is inside those tags that they hide. As seen now this question has too many possible answers to be answered definitively.

Comment: Accessibility, script usage, SEO, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it's beneficial to screen readers who will read that text to users with seeing difficulties.